# Pandas: number of rows where df['A'] == df['B'] or df['B'] == []

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

Consider following dataframe `df` with columns `A` and `B`. I am trying to find the number of rows where `df['A'] == df['B']` or `df['B'] == []`. How can I do this?

```
                  A                          B
m:QueryId       
970000000   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]      [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
970000001   [0]                                    [0]
970000002   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]                         []
970000003   [0, 1, 2, 3]                            []
970000004   [1, 2, 4]                            [5,6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with :

```
df[df['A'].eq(df['B'])|~df['B'].astype(bool)]
```

For count of such rows:

```
(df['A'].eq(df['B'])|~df['B'].astype(bool)).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, if you only want to compare list identity, do a simple comparison, for empty lists, if all elements are lists you can just check that its length is 0:

```
((df['A']==df['B'])|df['B'].str.len().eq(0)).sum()
```

output: `4`